# SSAS Tabular Model & Power BI - Week filtering in report

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services, datefilter

I created an SSAS Tabular Model in VS2017 and the model has a Date Table.

[image: Model UML Reference]

In the Data Table, I have measures to obtain the current week of the selected day (for my model, always `TODAY()`), and the weeks start on Monday and end on Sunday.

In my Power BI report I want to filter an entire page by the current week but if I use the "Relative Data Filtering" coming along with Power BI, the week starts at Sunday and ends on Monday. This leads to an error in the data display.

[image: Relative Data Filtering in Power BI]

Now, the SSAS Tabular Model is deployed to an Azure Analysis Services server, and the Power BI report connects to this. In this case, I am not able to configure in Power BI any regional settings.

How can I filter an entire report page by the formatted week I have?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221320/filter-a-column-dynamically-using-a-measure-in-power-bi/), you can create a calculated column on your calendar table, `Dates`, to determine which dates to include or exclude.

```
Dates[IncludeDate] = IF( Dates[Date] >= [StartOfWeek] && Dates[Date] <= [EndOfWeek], 1, 0 )
```

Then use `Dates[IncludeDate] is 1` as your filter.